# iOS: UIButton Autolayout size is zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

Using autolayout I want to understand why the following happens: Creating a simple UIButton and setting its title. However, even though I expect the intrinsic content size of the view to be set and hence get its frame properly - the frame of the button is showing (0, 0, 0, 0). What do I have to do to get the frame value of the button ?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [button.titleLabel setText:@"My button"];

    //button frame is zero

}
```

Yet if I am to do that, then things work as expected:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    [label setText:@"My label"];

    [label sizeToFit];

    //label frame has the expected width and height

}
```

Comment: you have not set the size then it always zero.!!

Comment: I don't set the size since I am using Autolayout. By having the code above - I expect to have a button with the title "My button" filling its content.

Comment: In autolayout you have to set constraints

Comment: Seems to be missing [self.view addSubview:label], if you don't add it won't the calculated in autolayout engine pass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autolayout sets views frame only after a layout pass, it's something that has cycle and is not called evertytime you add a view or modify constraints, that's why sometimes you need to call `-setNeedsLayout` on a particular view.
The other point is that if you do not create constraints using interface builder or programmatically, autolayout automatically converts the view autoresizing masks into constraints (`-translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property).
In this case if you set a text, you are forcing the view to express its intrinsic content size, that basically is the size of the label, if the intrinsic content size doesn't conflict to other constraints it wins, but you can only ask the button size after the layout pass. Try to check the button size inside `.viewDidLayout` after the call of the same method to the super class

Comment: Yeah I understand this, however, seems that UIButton does not have its intrinsic content size applied at this stage. Adding the button to the main view and printing its size on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` shows 0 0 again...

Comment: Is [super viewDidLayoutSubviews] called? try to ask for a setNeedsLayout on the main view after you add the label

Comment: @pe60t0 If you do not add the label as a subview it won't pass in autolayout calculation

Comment: I should have called `sizeToFit` on the button as well... This is what confused me. Thanks anyway - your answer helped me understand the problem.

Comment: No.. the basic version should work without calling sizeToFit and without setNeedsLayout.. "should" :D

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [button setTitle:@"My button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    //check frame of button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Andrea said: because you haven't added the button in IB, it is defaulting to using the autoResizingMask, which will keep the zero sized frame that the button initialised with.

If you want autolayout to work, you need to set

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

right before calling `-addSubview:`.

In addition, you'll have to add at least 1 horizontal constraint and 1 vertical constraint, to position the button. Even after you do that, the button's frame will only be set after the next layout pass, which you can manually initiate by calling `-layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: But that ain't true - the button should have its intrinsic content size defined regardless of its position in the view hierarchy

Comment: @pe60t0 yes, it should have an intrinsicContentSize, but the autoResizingMask constraints take priority over that. If you disable the autoResizingMask it'll kick in. sizeToFit worked for you because it manually set the frame to the intrinsicContentSize, but now, even if the content (i.e. title or image) changes, the size won't update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button as a sub view and call `layoutIfNeeded` on the subview. Access its frame after that.

Also make sure you add constraints for leading and top to position the button within its superview.

Comment: I can understand that a view needs to have a superview in order for the layout engine to calculate its frame. What I don't understand however, is if instead of using a button I use a label in the example above - then the size of the label is what I expect (after calling `sizeThatFits`). I Imagine the intrinsicContentSize of both a UILabel and UIButton will work in the same way ?