# UIButton.titleLabel.frame.size always with zero values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

i develop one project in xcode on Objective C. All was fine before last two days. Now all my buttons and other controls do not show their title text or images. I try to add new button from storyboard but it text still not showing. 
Also i try to add new button from code but result the same.

```
- (void) addTestButtonProgramatically {
    testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [testButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(testButtonSelector:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [testButton setTitle:@"TEST TEXT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [testButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.1 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
   testButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
   [self.view addSubview:testButton];
}


- (IBAction)testButtonSelector:(id)sender {
     [testButton.titleLabel sizeToFit]; //this row make text of my button shown
}
```

Maybe i mistakenly changed the setting which made such behavior. I try to lunch my project on another computer and issue is still there too.

Then i try to create new clear project and there everything was fine, text of buttons is visible.

Edit:

I find cause of  my issue. It was because i redefine - (void) layoutSubvies method on UIButton category.

```
@interface UIButton (Coordinator)
@end

@implementation UIButton (Coordinator)
- (void) layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];    
}
@end
```

Thens for all who help me find that.

Comment: where u called this method **addTestButtonProgramatically**

Comment: i call this method from - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated, before [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: instead of viewWillAppear add in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews. i hope this will help

Comment: Problem still here. I repeat the essence, all my buttons and navigationbar items showing without text and images, only if i make [button.titleLabel sizeToFit] it show text value.

Comment: call it from viewDidload..

Comment: I try, this is not help.

Comment: what is the frame of UIButton? is it also zero?

Comment: Frame of UIButton not is zero. Button background displays propertly.

Comment: may be this may help:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098993/4557505

Comment: Tnx, but this is not help me. I have read this already. In my case is something another.

Comment: Check the state of your button

Answer (score 1):

add `[testButton.titleLabel sizeToFit]` to `addTestButtonProgramatically` method. why are you fitting size of button's text in it's own click..?!. you should do it when you setup the button

Update :

```
 [self.button layoutIfNeeded]; // call this after adding button in view if you are using autolayout
```

Comment: I locate [testButton.titleLabel sizeToFit] to selector for visible that after click to button text appear. But as i know i size of titleLabel must be not zero value. I mean if i add new button from storyboard this button shown with hidden title text because button.titleLabel.frame.size.width and button.titleLabel.frame.size.height always is zero value.

Comment: so what you want to do now tell me? anything else ? or problem solved?

Comment: Problem not solved. I have project on which i work from two months. All was fine, but two days ago something was changed and now all my buttons shown on simulator without text and images. On debug i has seen that all titleLabel in my buttons has zero height and width value. Now i do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Also i try to lunch my project on another macbook and there text on buttons not shown too.

Comment: then set that button's title label's frame programatically

Comment: Why i must to set frame size for all my buttons. I have it a lot on my storyboard. And why earlier it was fine and now i must to write i lot of code.

Comment: Also on my navigation bar text and images gone too. How i can fix that case?

Comment: I think this issue relative whit something from project setting are some another. I have not done anything lately whit project setting.

Comment: What major changes you have done in last two or three days?

Comment: If you set title label frame manually then is it visible?? have you tried title color or tint color to check that titlecolor is not becoming transparent etc?

Comment: have you enable autolayout ? previously you are not usnig and then you start..! have you done this kind of changes?

Comment: I was library for Oauth https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client Also edit info.plist for catch redirect url. And that is all. As for about colors this is not relative whit it, because i after i set site of titleLabel it was shown, and earlier all was fine.

Comment: can find me on skype? This is my nick: coulddog

Comment: I am not using skype. what i am askingm have unable autolayout lateron ? mean you are not using autolayout before and now using. is it like so? if you are adding button programatically and not setting constraints and nearby object for exam view or other button have constraint then this kind of problem is possible

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021491/ios-uibutton-autolayout-size-is-zero  if it can help

Comment: Sorry, i use autholayout from beginning.

Comment: I ask for skype because, if you can you can connect to my computer via teamviewer. Maybe that can help me more faster.

Comment: No it is not mandatory but if you enable autolayout for particular view controller and if you giving constraints to some view and not giving to some then this can raise problem. according to your query i assume that you have working everything fine and suddenly get issue so it is possible that you have set constraints to neighbor views and buttons you are adding is programmatically

Comment: Thats i can understand but i am not using skype and teamviewer and i dont have access in my office. so sorry for that